# Excel - How do I ensure that when a value is entered into a cell, another is then blanked(and vice versa)?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have two columns in an excel spreadsheet - only one of those columns should be allowed to have a value in it. Lets call them Cells `A1` and `B1`.

I figure that I can facilitate this one of two ways:

1. When cell `A1` is changed it blanks out `B1`

   I can do this but then when it blanks out `B1`, it then fires off the same event and both cells get cleared.
2. If one of the cells has a value in it, then the other is somehow locked for editing until you clear the first cell.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks team!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable events to avoid clearing both cells; ie

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Range("A1,C1"))
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
If rng1.Address(0, 0) = "A1" Then
[c1].ClearContents
Else
[a1].ClearContents
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```